# Select batch of rows SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlperformance

I'm trying to retrieve a batch of rows and have achieved this using the row_number function, to for example retrieve the first 10,000 rows as follows:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         row_number() over (order by id) as row_num, * 
     from 
         forms) as batch
where 
    batch.row_num between 1 and 10000
```

This performs well first the first batch but becomes progressively slower as it reaches higher row numbers and one of the tables I'm using has > 2.7 million rows.

Is there any way to do this with a linear performance?

---

There's a clustered index on the primary key column and 5 other non-unique, non-clustered on some of the other columns. I'm processing the whole table in batches sequentially and have currently chosen 10,000 as the batch size. The 1-10,000 query takes less than a second but, for example, 200,000 - 210,000 takes 10 seconds and by the time it's in the millions it's > 1 minute.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? What is the use case? Processing the whole table in batches sequentially or seeking to an arbitrary batch?

Comment: There's a clustered index on the primary key column and 5 other non-unique, non-clustered on some of the other columns.  I'm processing the whole table in batches sequentially and have currently chosen 10,000 as the batch size.  The 1-10,000 query takes less than a second but, for example, 200,000 - 210,000 takes 10 seconds and by the time it's in the millions it's > 1 minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either remember the max id from the last batch and do a

```
SELECT top 10000 ... 
WHERE id > @maxid 
ORDER BY id
```

or you can use an [Api Cursor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68256/rejoining-range-seek-on-nullable-composite-index/68280#68280) to efficiently process a table in sequential chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes become useless when:

1.) Too much of such

2.) When table is poorly normalized.

As a rule-of-thumb:

1.) Keep the # of indexes at bay, 3-5 or less per table.

2.) Normalize your table up to the 3rd form if necessary. A well-normalized table addresses the proper # of indexes to be applied. The lesser the columns and NULL/duplicate values, the better the performance. One of the many reference about normalization: http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html

Another technique is to cluster your table - meaning you break the records to groups of tables. Each table would keep less than a million rows (more of like archiving). Then, of course, querying/adding up each table would be another story.